# GitHub Action Failed: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to implement a github action to deploy a django project to my Google Compute Engine but unable to.

I am following this tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-django-to-digitalocean-with-docker-and-github-actions/

The error log says:

> /home/runner/work/_temp/f***572db0-***32d-4053-8b60-f5d54780dd7c.sh:
>   line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

[image: error log]
I'm really not able to figure out what's wrong here.

```
name: Continuous Integration and Delivery

on: [push]

env:
  WEB_IMAGE: docker.pkg.github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/web
  CHANNELS_IMAGE: docker.pkg.github.com/$GITHUB_REPOSITORY/channels

jobs:

  build:
    name: Build Docker Images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Add environment variables to .env
        run: |
          echo DEBUG=0 >> .env
          echo SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql_pyscopg2 >> .env
          echo DATABASE=postgres >> .env
          echo SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }} >> .env
          echo SQL_DATABASE=${{ secrets.SQL_DATABASE }} >> .env
          echo SQL_USER=${{ secrets.SQL_USER }} >> .env
          echo SQL_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.SQL_PASSWORD }} >> .env
          echo SQL_HOST=${{ secrets.SQL_HOST }} >> .env
          echo SQL_PORT=${{ secrets.SQL_PORT }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_HOST=${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_PORT=${{ secrets.EMAIL_PORT }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_USE_TLS=${{ secrets.EMAIL_USE_TLS }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_HOST_USER=${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_USER }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD }} >> .env
          echo DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL=${{ secrets.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL }} .env
          echo ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL=http://ventinghub.com/auth/sign-in
          echo ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL=http://ventinghub.com/
          echo SITE_ID=1
          echo EMAIL_BACKEND=django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend
          echo redis_host=redis
      - name: Set environment variables
        run: |
          echo ::set-env name=WEB_IMAGE::${{ env.WEB_IMAGE }}
          echo ::set-env name=CHANNELS_IMAGE::${{ env.CHANNELS_IMAGE }}
      - name: Log in to GitHub Packages
        run: echo ${GITHUB_TOKEN} | docker login -u ${GITHUB_ACTOR} --password-stdin docker.pkg.github.com
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Pull images
        run: |
          docker pull ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE }} || true
          docker pull ${{ env.CHANNELS_IMAGE }} || true
      - name: Build images
        run: |
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.yml build
      - name: Push images
        run: |
          docker push ${{ env.WEB_IMAGE }}
          docker push ${{ env.CHANNELS_IMAGE }}

  deploy:
    name: Deploy to GCP
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Checkout master
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Add environment variables to .env
        run: |
          echo DEBUG=0 >> .env
          echo SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql_pyscopg2 >> .env
          echo DATABASE=postgres >> .env
          echo SECRET_KEY=${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }} >> .env
          echo SQL_DATABASE=${{ secrets.SQL_DATABASE }} >> .env
          echo SQL_USER=${{ secrets.SQL_USER }} >> .env
          echo SQL_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.SQL_PASSWORD }} >> .env
          echo SQL_HOST=${{ secrets.SQL_HOST }} >> .env
          echo SQL_PORT=${{ secrets.SQL_PORT }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_HOST=${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_PORT=${{ secrets.EMAIL_PORT }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_USE_TLS=${{ secrets.EMAIL_USE_TLS }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_HOST_USER=${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_USER }} >> .env
          echo EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD }} >> .env
          echo DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL=${{ secrets.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL }} .env
          echo ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL=http://ventinghub.com/auth/sign-in
          echo ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL=http://ventinghub.com/
          echo SITE_ID=1
          echo EMAIL_BACKEND=django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend
          echo redis_host=redis
      - name: Add the private SSH key to the ssh-agent
        env:
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK > /dev/null
          ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          ssh-add - <<< "${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}"
      - name: Build and deploy images on DigitalOcean
        env:
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
        run: |
          scp  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ./.env ./docker-compose.prod.yml root@${{ secrets.GCP_IP_ADDRESS }}:/app
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no goutambseervi@${{ secrets.GCP_IP_ADDRESS }} << 'ENDSSH'
            cd /app
            source .env
            docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u Goutam192002 -p e0fa37cae6211ae1b908c57766e582b6628af519
            docker pull $WEB_IMAGE
            docker pull $CHANNELS_IMAGE
            docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d
          ENDSSH
```

What is the error here? I've been scratching my head past 3 hours and I've no clue.

Answer (score 18):

My guess is that your secret called `SECRET_KEY` on line 4 of the run step contains a `)` character. Try escaping with quotes.

```
echo SECRET_KEY="${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}" >> .env
```

Comment: this is rather difficult to spot,  just curious how did you know this was the issue

Comment: The error message contains the line number of the run command, so it was just a guess that the secret was not being escaped.

Comment: I lost 4 hours figuring out the problem until I found this answer. Had the same extra  parenthesis problem ;/

Comment: @peterevans you sir, deserve a riase.